# Max Upload file size for Java using Remote object (BlazDS)?

Tags: java, apache-flex, flex3, blazeds

I tried with flex and java in the backend. In this, I am able to upload files till 100 MB using remote object (blazeDs) where we will read the file as byte array and send it to the java method. If the file size exceeds after that, then I get the run time error in IE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[100 MB is the maximum officially supported size](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/flash/net/FileReference.html)

> Although Flash Player has no restriction on the size of files you can upload or download, the player officially supports uploads or downloads of up to 100 MB.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, can you please guide me how to change the upload size in the player if my requirement is more then 100 mb.

Comment: @sri I don't think 100 MB is a strictly enforced limit - it's just that FP officially supports only upto that; am not aware of any settings to increase this

Comment: is this "limit" applied also on move/copy file in the local drive using AIR?!?